# How to save an camera photo with an image over top in Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, camera, swift3, photo

In my main view, I have a UIView, with an imageView in it where the camera preview gets pulled into, and a second imageView is basically a graphical border, that overlays the camera preview.

I am having a hard time finding any support for saving both of those images, when the user hits the "Save" button.

Here is my code thus far:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var pickedImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var photoFrame: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var photoWrapper: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func saveAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pickedImage.image!, 0.99)
    let compressedImage = UIImage(data: imageData!)
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(compressedImage!, nil, nil, nil)
}

@IBAction func cameraAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

@IBAction func libraryAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    pickedImage.image = image
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}
```

Right now, tapping the "cameraAction" button will show the camera, and allow you to take a photo, which when you hit "Use this photo", will load the captured photo into the "pickedImage" image view.

Ideally, I would like my photo frame overlay to be in the camera view as well - but - we'll tackle one issue at a time (unless whoever is reading this knows a way to make that happen in the same answer).

My primary concern however is getting it so that the saveAction can capture the photo AND the overlay image into one. Right now, I can see that the code creates a UIImageJPEGRepresentation out of the photo view... so I guess the big question is - would I be able to add a second image into that (I'm guessing not), or, do I have to utilize some other method to combine the two photos into one, and THEN call the UIImageJPEGRepresentation?

Answer (score 1):

Wrote this function in a playground and it works to overlay one image on top of another.  You can call UIImageJPEGRepresentation on the resulting composite image.

```
    func composite(image:UIImage, overlay:(UIImage), scaleOverlay: Bool = false)->UIImage?{
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
        var rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
        image.draw(in: rect)
        if scaleOverlay == false {
            rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: overlay.size.width, height: overlay.size.height)
        }
        overlay.draw(in: rect)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
```

Comment: This almost works - except the overlay photo is super tiny, and is reversed & upside down. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Edited the source to add an optional scaling parameter and changed to UIKit methods; I forgot CoreGraphics is upside-down on iOS with respect to Mac.  Note you should use a bigger overlay that is the same aspect ratio as the camera (4:3) or its going to look weird when you scale it.